# WSO2 ESB: SFTP file transfer: Auth Fail

Tags: wso2, sftp, vfs, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2. I was trying to move file with transport vfs module from my local (windows) to sftp server. I am able to achieve the desired results with this proxy service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
    name="SFTPProxy"
    transports="vfs"
    startOnLoad="true">
    <description/>
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="STATUS:" value="---------SFTP Proxy Invoked-------------------"/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///C:/Program Files/WSO2/Enterprise_Integrator/6.5.0/generates/</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:///C:/Program Files/WSO2/Enterprise_Integrator/6.5.0/generates/failed/</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities">/C:/Program Files/WSO2/Enterprise_Integrator/6.5.0/key/****.pem</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://****@*******</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentityPassPhrase">****</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Then I moved on to try this on my server (Ubuntu). But I am having Auth Fail error. Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SFTPProxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="vfs">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS:" value="---------SFTP Proxy Invoked-------------------"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///home/*****/maersk-configs/generates/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:///home/*****/maersk-configs/generates/failed/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities">/home/*****/.ssh/key.pem</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.xml</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://****@********</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentityPassPhrase">****</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.AvoidPermissionCheck">true</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Here is exception stack. Guide me please.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-11-20 10:00:19,161]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS: = ---------SFTP Proxy Invoked------------------- {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-11-20 10:00:20,378] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener} -  Error resolving directory to move after processing : sftp://****@*********** {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://****@*******".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:86)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:149)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:111)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:81)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:778)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:658)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:667)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:504)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:134)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "**********".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:164)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:79)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:162)
        ... 15 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-11-20 10:00:20,380] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener} -  File object 'file:///home/****/maersk-configs/generates/BK-2807-Booking-1.xml'cloud not be moved, will remain in "locked" state {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error resolving directory to move after processing : sftp://****@*********
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleException(AbstractTransportListener.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:715)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:504)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:134)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://****@********/".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:86)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:149)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:111)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:81)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:778)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:658)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:667)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "*********".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:164)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:79)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:162)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Can you check whether you can connect to the SFTP server from your ubuntu server using an SFTP client like WinSCP?

Comment: Actually I have not that much independence on Ubuntu server. I am connecting to it via putty

Comment: I think you can check the connection using the terminal. Check this link https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-use-ftp-on-the-linux-shell/

Comment: @PramodyaMendis I am able to connect to server using this command on terminal

" sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -i .ssh/key.pem ******@**************** "

Comment: Hi @WaleedAhmadQureshi,
Did u get solution for this?bcoz i am facing the same issue